# Doxygen link points to the detailed examination part of the class

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am now using Doxygen to generate documents for a C++ class:

```
/** brief introduction to the class
*
*  detailed explanations are here.
*
/
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass()
   ...
 }
```

When I write something in the mainpage part, I want to point to the detailed explanation part of the class:

```
/*! \mainpage a library
*
*
*   link to the detailed explanation part of the class: MyClass
*/
```

However, the link will lead me to the class reference part, but not the detailed explanation part. I have to hit *More...* in the brief explanation part of the class in order to get the detailed part as the following picture shows:
[image]
Any ideas on how I can get the link to the detailed explanation part of the class? Thanks.

Comment: That picture mostly just shows bad Paint skills

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by accident. What I did is to first define a module name if this class

```
/**
* @addtogroup mymodule
*/
```

After that,

```
/** brief introduction to the class
*
*  detailed explanations are here.
*
*  @ingroup mymodule
/
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass()
   ...
 }
```

Then everything will be fine.